# Breaking out of a loop with a keypress

Tags: c++, break, conio

I am writing a Win32 GUI app which has a loop which I would like to restart only when a keypress is made. The main loop is already running, and I can't simply restart it, so I have to insert a 'hang' point which the user can manually break out of. The code below represents what I have put at the end of my main loop. It is supposed to pause the program by putting it into an endless sub-loop which can only be broken when  the letter 'q' is pressed.

```
for (;;)
 {
 char temp;
 temp = _getch();

 if (temp == 'q')
  {
  break;
  }
 }
```

This successfully makes the program hang, but pressing 'q' does nothing to end the loop. I understand that using cin.ignore() or cin.get() would be preferable, but for some reason when I add iostream to the header list, I get a bunch of errors, so I am currently trying to do it using _getch() with the conio.h header.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `if(temp == 'q')` would make your code much more readable.

Comment: Just curious, but what errors are you getting from the headers?

Comment: are you sure your program reaches this loop? have you verified it?

Comment: Doing an infinite loop is not the correct strategy for "pausing" a program unless you want test the speed of your fan.

Comment: @MGZero, these are a couple of the errors I get when I add iostream:1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acosf'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C2059: syntax error : ';'

Comment: Also, you might want to type cast that 113 to a char, or just say 'q'.

Comment: @Felice: AFAIK `getch` blocks

Comment: @yi_H yes, the program definitely reaches the loop, as it didn't hang before I added it

Comment: @Nobody and MGZero: Thanks, I've changed to make the code more readable now

Comment: is your source file extension .c or .cpp?

Comment: Probably a dumb question, and not meant to be offensive, but you do press 'q' followed by enter right? :-)

Comment: @love_me_some_linux No, pressing enter doesn't work either. However I wonder is it possible that between pressing 'q' and 'enter' since the loop restarts perhaps it throws out the 'q'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call `MessageBox`.

Comment: Genius! Thanks, will try that instead

Comment: Just checkin' (noob here) - will a messagebox pause my main program?

Comment: `MessageBox` is modal, so it will block whichever thread called it until the user chooses an option or closes the window.

Comment: Thanks. In this situation, this has worked perfectly. The program hangs and until I press Enter, the program is paused.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your question, but it sounds like you're trying to prompt the user after each iteration of a loop if they wish to continue. I assume that the infinite `for` loop is at the end of your main processing loop.

You don't need the infinite loop: `_getch()` will halt execution anyway until a key is pressed. In truth, the fact that you've wrapped your conditional in a `for` loop is the reason that `break` isn't behaving like you want -- you're `break`ing out of the infinite loop, but not your main processing loop.

Example:

```
while(1)
{
   // Do some processing
   for (;;)
   {
      char temp;
      temp = _getch();

      if (temp == 'q')
         break;   // This will break out of the for and continue the while
   }
}
```

vs.

```
while(1)
{
   // Do some processing
   if ('q' == _getch())
      break;             // This will break out of the while
}
```

You'll also notice that since _getch() returns a `char`, you can just test the return code of the function (unless you need to store the input for later use).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a message loop and wait until a keydown message arrives. [Try to check this example](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=397239).

In a windows GUI application there is no input to read from the console.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned this is a Win32 GUI application. At the time of entering the loop, have you created any Windows that might have the input focus? if yes you should try trapping [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28VS.85%29.aspx)/[WM_KEYUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28VS.85%29.aspx) messages. If it is a console application, look at **[Console Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28VS.85%29.aspx)** specially **[ReadConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684958%28VS.85%29.aspx)**.

Sam